# Bumping / displacement with low-poly rock

Tags: bump

Good afternoon.

I made a low poly rock and try to apply a texture with a bump effect, but the result looks not very realistic.
What could be the problem?

[image: with bumping]

[image: without bumping]

[image: shading nodes]

[image: model]

------------------------- update --------------------------------------------

I changed Datail to 5.0 and scale to 26.0 and added MixRGB.

Results:

1 - fac = 0.5

2 - fac = 0.86

3 - fac = 0.95

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: probably because it mixes low poly shape with high poly details

Comment: Try using a checkerboard texture to see if there's no excessive stretching going on in the UV map.

Comment: Increase the detail of your Noise Texture to 5 and increase the scale to something more like 20 or 30 and see if that helps. Also, use a MixRGB node to mix the Noise Texture heavily (like in the 98% area) with white before connecting it to the displacement node.